# Querying Hive data located on a remote cluster using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I'm trying to write a simple Scala code that queries Hive data located on a remote cluster. My code will be deployed to a clusterA but has to query a Hive table located on clusterB. I'm developing this in my local Eclipse and getting the following error

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table not found: `<mydatabase>`.`<mytable>`;
```

The relevant part of my code is below

```
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Xing")
    .setMaster("local[*]")
    conf.set("hive.metastore.uris","thrift://<clusterB url>:10000")
    val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)
    val hc = new HiveContext(sc)
    val df = hc.sql("select * from <mydatabase>.<mytable>")
```

I suspect it is a configuration issue but I may be wrong. Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you run beeline and access the same HiveServer/database/table?

Comment: I can query this table using Hive JDBC with no problems. This cluster has Kerberos security setup. I was trying to set the same properties in SparkConf but had the same error. These are the properties I'm setting:
      conf.set("login.user","<value>")
  conf.set("keytab.file", "<value>")
  conf.set("sun.security.krb5.debug","false")
  conf.set("java.security.krb5.conf","<value>")
  conf.set("java.library.path","<value>")
  conf.set("hadoop.home.dir","<value>")
  conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication","kerberos")

Answer (score 0):

The port in the metastore URL should be 9083, unless you purposely changed it. 10000 is for hiveserver2.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. However, I am getting the same error with either port